# Why does my edit & delete methods return a "404 not found" when my index & create routes work

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Laravel version has updated and the routes is now expecting an object instead of an id from when i last used it.

My Routes:
[image: Routes]
[image: Routes Resource]

When I try to pass over the $item object which the method in the controller wants. I get a 404 not found and my logs aren't returning... meaning the function isn't running. When the $item obj is not passed over the function realizes that a parameter is missing thus the method is recognized by the blade as being the same as the one in the controller.

Calling the edit function in Blade:

[image: Blade code]

Controller Code:

[image]

I appreciate any help whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your routes is probably wrong

when you first define the show route with `/item/{item}` and then create with `/item/create` laravel will think the "create" is the id (or reference)

best way is to have

1. the index
2. create
3. ....
4. show

Code Example correct

```php
    Route::get('/', ProductIndex::class)->name('product.index');
    Route::get('/new', ProductCreate::class)->name('product.create');
    Route::get('/{product}', ProductShow::class)->name('product.show');
```

Code Example wrong

```php
    Route::get('/', ProductIndex::class)->name('product.index');
    Route::get('/{product}', ProductShow::class)->name('product.show');
    Route::get('/new', ProductCreate::class)->name('product.create');
```

Comment: Thanks, I called each route individually and it's now calling the method.